# How to test an async error/exception handler in express with jest

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, jestjs, tdd

I'm new to development and I'm trying to build my first project with TDD. I got this function (handleAsync) from a tutorial supposed to catch errors in async route handlers. To truly understand how it works, I am trying to come up with some tests.

**./utils/handle-async.js**

```
// ./utils/handle-async.js
module.exports = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {
  fn(req, res, next).catch((err) => next(err));
};
```

**./tests/utils/handle-async.test.js**

```
// ./tests/utils/handle-async.test.js
const handleAsync = require('../../utils/handle-async');

describe('catch errors in async functions', () => {
  it('should throw an error if a promise is rejected or an error occurs', (done) => {
    // const fn=async()=>await Promise.resolve(1)
    const fn = async () => Promise.reject(new Error('Rejected!'));

    expect(handleAsync(fn)).toThrowError('Rejected!');

    done();
  });

  it('should not throw and error if a promise is resolved', (done) => {
    // yet to be written, don't know what to do here since first test shows I don't get it yet

  });
});
```

I get the following error

> ● catch errors in async functions › should throw an error if a promise is rejected or an error occurs
>
> expect(received).toThrowError(expected)
>
> Expected substring: "Rejected!"
>
> Received function did not throw
>
> ```
>   7 |     // console.log(typeof fn);
>   8 |     // console.log('rejected prom:', fn);
>  *9 |     expect(handleAsync(fn)).toThrowError('Rejected!');
>     |                             ^
>  10 |     done();
>  11 |   });
>  12 |
>
>  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/utils/handle-async.test.js:9:29)
> ```

I'm probably doing some super dumb things but if anyone could help and/or point me in the right directions, that would be awesome. Don't hesitate to say whatever is wrong/stupid. I'm eager to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that `handleAsync` doesn't execute the handler - it only creates the middleware. You're also expecting it to *not* throw, but rather to pass the error on via the `next` callback. That's the reason you're using a middleware like this - so you can have `async` route handlers and have any possible errors be passed automatically to `next` so that the errors get passed to your [error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

You can test whether it actually catches a promise rejection from a wrapped route handler. Here's an example, which I haven't had the chance to test:

```
describe("catch errors in async functions", () => {
  it("should catch rejected promises and pass the error to next", (done) => {
    const rejectError = new Error("Rejected!");
    const fn = async () => Promise.reject(rejectError);

    const middleware = handleAsync(fn);

    const req = {};
    const res = {};
    const next = (err) => {
      expect(err).toBe(rejectError);
      done();
    };

    middleware(req, res, next);
  });
});
```

There's also a package called [`express-async-handler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler/v/1.1.4) which provides the same functionality as your `handleAsync`. You might be interested in taking a look [how it does its tests](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler/blob/ccd9b5b9b0bbe853ec3374cb76ee0d7b81b736a3/test.js).